# windows 8 zombie processes

Tags: windows, memory-leaks, zombie-process

Due to a problem I can't track down, all dead processes remain as page entries (16 kB page data, 4 kB reserved private memory).  As you might expect, this builds up over time and it's making it tough to run games.  I can find the processes on Rammap using this memory.

What I'm looking for is a script that will clear out all these zombie processes.  It's a real hassle to reset my computer twice a day if I want to game, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much!
~ZK

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue. In my case, zombie processes are the artifacts of a build system based on make. Each time I run a build, a lot of processes are created by make, and they pile up on my memory. At some point, RAM becomes full and I cannot start one more application. And I'm using Windows 7.